# Почему не получается вставить запись в базу данных MS SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, база-данных

Вчера база работала нормально. А сегодня при попытке вставки новой строки получаю:
[image]

Вроде бы все написано русским языком. Но все равно не пойму что произошло.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Похоже, что вы пытаетесь изменить записи, используя GUI.
В этом случае таблица обязательно должна иметь первичный (уникальный) ключ.
Однако вы можете внести изменение кодом с помощью оператора [UPDATE](http://www.sql-tutorial.ru/ru/book_update_statement.html), даже если ключа нет.

Answer (score 2):

Это скорее всего значит, что вы пытались сделать вставку записи в поле где заведен уникальный индекс (значения должны быть неповторяющиеся) - обычно первичный ключ.

Comment: Я тоже так сначала подумал. Но в этой таблице не было первичного ключа и индексов. А хуже того, что когда я нажал кнопку "Выполнить код SQL" данные в таблице все пропали.

Comment: @derkode, так, давайте сюда тот код, который вы выполняли.

Comment: Я вручную вставляю с помощью Management Studio. Пытаясь выяснить в чем дело, я нажал там эту кнопку.